# how to split the last element in the string

Tags: python

I am trying to split the last element from the build_location if it is same as the previous element,however the expected ouput is not the same,can you help on how to fix it?

```
build_location = "\\data\builds797\PROD\client.1.8-01180-STD.PROD-1\client.1.8-01180-STD.PROD-1"

buildid =build_location.split("\\")


if buildid[-1] == buildid[-2]:
    #split the last element after "\"
    build_location = build_location.split("\\")[-1]
print build_location

OUTPUT:-
client.1.8-01180-STD.PROD-1

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

\\data\builds797\PROD\client.1.8-01180-STD.PROD-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
build_location = build_location.split("\\")[-1]
```

To:

```
build_location = build_location.split("\\")[:-1]
#                                        ---^---
```

You want take all the element except the last one rather than just the last one.

That's called **slicing** and you can learn about it.

After that you should merge the list back to one string and add the extra `\` with:

```
'\\'+'\\'.join(build_location)
```

Comment: The beginning needs a double backlash "\\" like `\\datuilds797\PROD\client.1.8-01180-STD.PROD-1` ,with this we miss it

Comment: @user3682248 fixed that for you

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're only indexing the last element. You should use a *slice* to exclude the last item not an *index* on the last item:

```
if buildid[-1] == buildid[-2]:
    #split the last element after "\"
    build_location = build_location.split("\\")[:-1]
    #                                          ^^^^^
```

Or better, perform the *slicing* on the already splitted `buildid` to avoid *resplitting*:

```
if buildid[-1] == buildid[-2]:
    #split the last element after "\"
    build_location = buildid[:-1]
```

---

Then, to rebuild the original string from the *slice*, use `join`:

```
build_location = "\\".join(build_location)
```

Comment: The beginning needs a double backlash "\\" like `\\datuilds797\PROD\client.1.8-01180-STD.PROD-1` ,with this we miss it

Comment: @user3682248 You can add manually that. `build_location = "\\" + "\\".join(build_location)` should do